# How to close tab/window which wasn't open programatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I close a tab/window which wasn't opened programmatically?
I have tried the following code:

```
parent.window.close;
```

This only works for programmatically opened tabs not for manually open ones.

Comment: `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`

Comment: is there any other programatically way to close that tab which wasn't opened by script?

Comment: You could try using a browser extension. Why do you want to close the tab?

Comment: bowser extension means it will be specific to browser i want more generic solution for all browser.

Comment: Then you need to create a browser extension for each browser. Why do you want to close a tab not opened by your script?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close tabs / windows that aren't the same tab / window that the code is running in.

To close the current tab / window use [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close):

```
window.close();
```

Comment: @Aryan did this help?

Comment: No it didn't help